# Laravel 5.4 won't sync models

Tags: model, eloquent, laravel-5.4

I'm trying to get two models that have a defined relationship to sync, but when attempting this, one side of the equation is blank.

One model has a primary key that is not of the usual convention, but I have defined this in the relationship and in the model under $primaryKey

**Model One (LinesCompany):**

```php
class LinesCompany extends Model
{
    protected $table = 'lines_companies';
    protected $primaryKey = 'participant_id';

    public $incrementing = false;

    public function fuel()
    {
        return $this->belongsToMany(Fuel::class, 'fuel_lines_company', 'participant_id', 'fuel_id');
    }
}
```

**Model Two (Fuel):**

```php
class Fuel extends Model
{
    public function linesCompany()
    {
        return $this->belongsToMany(LinesCompany::class, 'fuel_lines_company', 'fuel_id', 'participant_id');
    }
}
```

**Table (fuel_lines_company):**

```php
id (primary) | fuel_id (foreign) | participant_id (foreign points to lines_companies table)
```

**Code:**

```php
public function addLinesCompany(Request $request, $linesCompany)
{
    $LinesCompany = new LinesCompany;
    $LinesCompany->participant_id = $linesCompany;
    $LinesCompany->code = $request->get('linesCode');
    $LinesCompany->geography = $request->get('geo');
    $LinesCompany->website = $request->get('web');
    $LinesCompany->emergency_number = $request->get('phone');
    $LinesCompany->review_process = $request->get('review');

    try{
        DB::beginTransaction();

        $LinesCompany->save();

        $LinesCompany->id = $LinesCompany->participant_id;

        $LinesCompany->fuel()->sync($request->get('linesFuel'));

        DB::commit();

        return true;

    } catch(PDOException $e){
        DB::rollback();

        return 'An error occured adding the Lines Company.';
    }
}
```

**Exception Message:**

```php
(3/3) QueryException
SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation: 1048 Column 'participant_id' cannot be null (SQL: insert into `fuel_lines_company` (`fuel_id`, `participant_id`) values (2, ))
```

Hoping someone might be able to see where I am going wrong to resolve this one.

Thanks

Comment: What's the exception message?

Comment: Oops meant to put that. Edited question to include it at the bottom

Comment: What's your exact Laravel version?

Comment: @JonasStaudenmeir 5.4.36

Comment: What's the value of `$linesCompany`?

Comment: haha thanks @JonasStaudenmeir it would be *null* fixed that part and now it works fine. Assumed it was working ok as the $LinesCompany->save() appeared to be working fine